# Google Maps API v2 for Android: Marker and Polyline position mismatch

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to draw some markers and a polyline in the same map this way

```
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    Marker marker;

    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyLineOptions.color(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mm_red));

    if (route != null) {

        for(Entry entry : route.getEntries().getEntryList()){

            LatLng pos = new LatLng(entry.getGeolocation().getLatitude(), entry.getGeolocation().getLongitude());
            options.position(pos);
            polyLineOptions.add(pos);

            marker = mMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.im_map_marker_main_num)));
            marker.setVisible(true);

        }


    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    polyline.setVisible(true);

    }
```

However, here you can see the result I get:

[image: Markers and Polyline mismatch]

As you can see, even if I pass the same `LatLng` position to both `MarkerOptions` and `PolylineOptions`, there is some kind of offset.

As extra information, I get this behaviour in a Nexus 7.

Thank you

Edit: The marker icon's pin location is the default one, so the center of the bottom side of it
[image: Default marker image]

Edit: Not bitmap creation problem. If I use `canvas.drawColor`, this is what I get (different size, because now I'm with a Nexus 10)

[image: drawcolor not working]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that by default, the pin location of the `Marker` is at the bottom center of the image.

You will have to fiddle with [`anchor(float, float)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor%28float,%20float%29) and / or make sure the sharp edge is the last pixel on the bottom center (with no transparent pixels below).

Comment: Hi MaciejGórski,
All the icons I use have their pin position centered in the default place (the middle of the bottom size).
Thank you :-)

Comment: @Wakka You seem to be drawing this icon into `Bitmap`. Can you fill the background with `canvas.drawColor`?

Comment: @MaciejGórksi Thanks but it still doesn't work (look above in the second Edit) :-)

Comment: At the end I solved it playing with anchor values. It's not the best solution, but it is the one that works. Thanks.

Comment: @Wakka That's strange. Can you make a simple app on github to show the issue? Then maybe post on gmaps-api-issues if that is really not a problem with your code.